# effect of different groups on Amine inversion

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, amines

I know different groups attached to the nitrogen atom affect the amine inversion barrier, but is it due to steric factors or orbital interaction factors, eg. $\ce{(i-Pr)2NMe}$ vs $\ce{NCl3}$.

Comment: Both of those matter.